# Dojo TreeGrid with computed values in summary row

Tags: dojo

I am developing a treegrid and have an object being passed into a formatter to generate a gfx graphic.

```
},{
                                    field:"projects", name:"Projects", children:[
                                        {field:"name", name:"Project Name", formatter: projectFormatter},
                                        {field:"actual_cost", name:"Cost", width:'220px', formatter: costFormatter},
                                        {field:"budget", name:"Budget"}
                                    ],
                                    aggregate: "cnt",
                                    itemAggregates: ["actual_cost"]

                                }
```

now the formatter function should be able to use this data....however for the life of me, I cannot get it to compute the values in the formatter

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Try passing a nameless function to the formatter:

```
...,formatter: function(value){return getExtImg(value);},...
```

In there you can call your custom function by name. Dont forget to return a value in your formatter function !